# Gauss-Jacobi Method in Python without Numpy

Tags: python

I am supposed to make a function that uses Gauss-Jacobi method to solve an augmented matrix but can't figure out why my solution is always [0,0,0]. Here is what I have:

```
from copy import deepcopy
# Define function
def GaussJacobi(MyA, MyX, xtol=1e-6, maxiter=50):
    # MyA=Aaug=augmented matrix
    # MyX=x=vector(array) containing inital guess
    # xtol=exit condition, xnew-xold is less than xtol
    # maxiter=max number of iterations allowed before exiting
    #b=equation answers from augmented matrix
    n=len(MyA)
    x=deepcopy(MyX)
    sum=0
    b = [0] * len(MyA)
    lastcol = len(MyA[0]) - 1
    for i in range(len(b)):
        b[i] = MyA[i][lastcol]

        for iter in range(maxiter):
            for row in range(n-3):
                for col in range(n-3):
                    sum=b[col]-MyA[row][col]*x[col]
                x[row]=sum/MyA[row][col]
    return x


MyA = [[4, -1, -1, 3],
   [-2, 6, 1, 9],
   [-1, 1, 7, -6]]

MyX = [0, 0, 0]
print(GaussJacobi(MyA, MyX, xtol=1e-6, maxiter=50))
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should not be using integer division as you have been doing
i.e. `3/4 = 0` in this case rather than what you should be doing which is to use

```
3/float(4) = 0.75
```

This is not what is wrong with your code. You should try debugging statements, place print statements at appropriate places like the place where `x` is set. This lead me to see that you were not even entering this point since `n = len(myA) = 3` so `n - 3 = 0` so the inner loops were messed up.

There are bunch of other issues as you are not truly summing up terms you infact just reset sums - Without redoing the whole code (which is what I wanted to do!) I can not answer for sure why it is `0` but i can tell you even if it was not `0` the non-zero result would most likely be wrong.

The non-numpy part is presumably you tried to follow [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) - You should copy this and use a formula for the dot product.